# Python time.sleep syntax error

Tags: python, windows, time, syntax

I'm writing a short program that makes it look like the computer is being hacked.
I'm going to run it and leave the computer lying around and see how people react.

However, I am getting this syntax error when I try to use `time.sleep.`
can someone please help?

```
import time
print("Connecting to Server...")
print("Connected!")
response = input("Proceed with Hack? Y/N: ")
if response == "Y":
    {
    print("Uploading File: 10%")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Uploading File: 20%")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Uploading File: 30%")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Uploading File: 40%")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Uploading File: 50%")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Uploading File: 60%")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Uploading File: 70%")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Uploading File: 80%")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Uploading File: 90%")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Uploading File: 99%")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("File Uploaded!")
    print("Virus Injection Started...")
    time.sleep(6)
    print("Virus Injection Complete!")
    }
```

Comment: What are the `{}` supposed to be doing? Mixing languages?

Comment: indicating where the if starts and stops? I may be getting mixed up with java syntax here :/

Comment: Python uses indentation not braces, remove the `{}` and your code will work

Comment: Thank you! I'm an idiot haha

Comment: Try `from __future__ import braces` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't use curly braces, that's probably the cause of your syntax error, just use tabs to indent.

Answer (score 1):

You are using curly braces and they are not python's syntax for `if` statements, nor for loops (`for, while`). The curly braces are used in other programming languages. For example C and Java use curly braces to define the lines of code that belong to an `if` statement, but it is not like that in Python.

In Python just remember that each line starting with an indentation of 4 spaces will belong to the code executed when entering the `if`. This Python's syntax also extends to loops, functions definitions, classes definitions... keep that in mind as well.

For your code remove the curly braces and keep the indentation.

As a simple example:

```
a = 0

if a == 0:
    a = 1 # This line is inside the if statement
    b = 1 # This line is also inside the if statement

a = 2 # Outside the if statement
```